# Spring boot security not work hasRole('ADMIN')

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want the html blocks I specify below to be shown or hidden based on the Role accessing the platform.

I put the code, with the different possibilities that I raise:

I have the following code in html with SpringBootSecurity version 5:

```
<li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('write_user')" class="nav-item menu-closed" >
```

Setting an authority works for me, but since it is a block that will only be accessed by admins, I would like it to be by role:

No prefix:

```
<li  sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" class="nav-item menu-closed" >
```

Por lo que leí en esta nueva versión ya se usa directamente con hasAuthority y el Rol, pero así tampoco me funciona:

```
<li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')" class="nav-item menu-closed" >
```

The html contains:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
```

My user class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails, CredentialsContainer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
   // @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @Column
    //@NotBlank
    private String username;

    @Column
  //  @NotBlank
    private String surnames;


    @Column
    private String password;

    @Transient
   // @NotBlank
    private String confirmPassword;

    @Column(unique = true)
    //@NotBlank
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String profilePicture;

    @Transient
   // @NotBlank
    private String confirmEmail;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_team", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id"))
    private Set<Team> team;


    @Singular
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<Role> roles;


    @Transient
    public Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.roles.stream()
                .map(Role::getAuthorities)
                .flatMap(Set::stream)
                .map(authority -> {
                    return new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getPermission());
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Timestamp createdDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp lastModifiedDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp deletedDate;


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return this.accountNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return this.accountNonLocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return this.credentialsNonExpired;
    }


    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }

    @Builder.Default
    private Boolean accountNonExpired = true;

    @Builder.Default
    private Boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    @Builder.Default
    private Boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;

    @Builder.Default
    private Boolean enabled = true;

    @Override
    public void eraseCredentials() {
        this.password = null;
    }
```

I have tried all the ways I show in the html blocks above, but it doesn't work for me. Only if I use hasAuthority(). What I want is that
the block affects all the users that have that role, not the more specific permissions of each role that we give through the authorities. On the one hand there are the roles, these are divided into authorities to be able to be more specific with the permissions. I want hasRole(Admin) to see an HTML block, independently of its authorities.

Comment: authorities and roles are the same thing. If you use `hasRole` it will always prefix with `ROLE_`. So if you have an authoritu/role named `ADMIN` it doesn't match `ROLE_ADMIN`.